# Not getting values in query even after implementing DISTINCT in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query where I want distinct values but with below query it's not working. Tried with `ROW_NUMBER`

```sql
SELECT distinct sap_id, CASE
      WHEN operatorname IN( 'VIOM', 'idea', 'ATC',
                            'Vodafone', 'IDEA' ) THEN
      Cast(
      'ATC TELECOM INFRASTRUCTURE PVT LTD' AS
      NVARCHAR2(50))
      WHEN operatorname IN( 'GTL', 'CNIL' ) THEN Cast(
      'GTL INFRASTRUCTURE LTD' AS NVARCHAR2(50))
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'Ascend' ) THEN Cast(
      'ASCEND TELECOM INFRASTRUCTURE'AS NVARCHAR2(50))
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'Tower Vision (TVIPL)' )
    THEN
      Cast(
      'TOWER VISION INDIA PVT LTD'AS NVARCHAR2(50))
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'INDUS' ) THEN Cast(
      'INDUS TOWERS LTD'AS NVARCHAR2(50))
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'Bharti Infratel' ) THEN
      Cast(
      'BHARTI INFRATEL LIMITED'AS NVARCHAR2(50))
      ELSE operatorname
    END OPERATORNAME,
    CASE
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'VIOM', 'idea', 'ATC',
                             'Vodafone', 'IDEA' )
                    THEN
      '3150909'
      WHEN operatorname IN( 'GTL', 'CNIL' ) THEN
      '3164892'
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'Ascend' ) THEN '3155709'
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'Tower Vision (TVIPL)' )
    THEN
      '3157870'
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'INDUS' ) THEN '3578944'
      WHEN operatorname IN ( 'Bharti Infratel' ) THEN
      '3147912'
      ELSE ''
    END VENDOR_CODE,
    rj_company_code_1,
    city_name,
    ne_id,                            
    latitude,
    longitude,
    row_number() over (partition by SAP_ID
    order by SAP_ID desc) as rn                              
FROM   r4g_osp.enodeb
WHERE  priority_site = 'IP1'
    AND scope IN( 'EnodeB-Connected_Fibre',
                  'EnodeB-Connected_MW' )
    AND jcpstatus = 'On Air'                            
    AND sap_id IN (SELECT SAP_ID FROM TEMP_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; a **MINIMAL** query that represents the problem (don't include a 2-page query if you can simplify the problem down to 5-10 lines); an English explanation of the problem ("it's not working" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us what is not working); and the expected output for your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and `DISTINCT` at the same time as `ROW_NUMBER` will give each row a unique number and `DISTINCT` will look at all the values including the row number and try to remove duplicates - which won't happen because each row will have a unique row number.

For example, if you have a minimal table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY 1) AS rn
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

| ID | RN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Which gives a unique number/id pairing to all each row and `DISTINCT` is pointless.

But:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       id
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

And `DISTINCT` can actually remove the duplicates.

Alternatively, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` without `DISTINCT` and filter using an inline view:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY 1) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which outputs the same as the previous query using only `DISTINCT`.

But trying to use `ROW_NUMBER` and `DISTINCT` in the same (sub) query is pointless.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ijd1rUC2)

Comment: then what can be used to get distinct values ?

Comment: @hud `DISTINCT` on its own.